# How to return value to C# application from php web-service

Tags: c#, php, mysql, json, web-services

I have a c# windows form application. I send three values (username, password and token) through to a PHP web-service, to verify and login to application.

My C# Windows form application code:

```
 private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtusername.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please insert username");
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpassword.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please insert password");
    }

    var username = txtusername.Text;
    var password = txtpassword.Text;
    string Token = "28956";
    var SoftwareToken = token;
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://mydomain.com.au/Verification.php?username=username&password=password&Token=SoftwareToken");
    request.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.  
    var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    responseFromServer.ToArray();
    /*I have tried:
    responseFromServer.ToArray();(because result on php page is an array.
    I have tried responseFromServer.ToString();*/
    MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
}
```

My PHP Web-Service code:

```
<?php
// Database Structure 
require_once('connect.php');

//Get password from the database for the user
$stmtus = $conn->prepare("SELECT password from `Users` where `email` = :Username");
$stmtus->bindParam(':Username', $username);
$username= $_GET['username'];;
$stmtus -> execute();
$password = $stmtus->fetch();

$un = $_GET['username'];
$pw = $_GET['password'];
$ust = $_GET['Token'];

if(password_verify($pw, $password[0])){
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT 
COUNT(Token) AS cnt FROM `SoftwareToken` 
LEFT JOIN User ON iduser = SoftwareToken.Consultant 
WHERE Token = '$ust' 
AND username = '$un'");
$stmt->bindValue(':Username', $un);
$stmt->bindValue(':Token', $ust);
$stmt->execute();
$result= array();
while($SToken= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
array_push($result, $SToken->cnt);  
}
echo json_encode($result);

}

$conn = null;

?>
```

It seems like my code is working. I am trying to display the result in a `MessageBox.Show()` as a test. The end purpose is to use the return value in an if statement. The return value should be a an array of either 0 or 1.

The if statements will be:

```
        if (responseFromServer= 1)
        {
            Form1 identykidzform = new Form1();
            identykidzform.Show();

            Password loginform = new Password();
            loginform.Close();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

When i call the `MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer)` it is empty.

Please help me to display and use the return variable.

Comment: The PHP code will not returning anything if the password is not verified. This is not really very good because it doesn't tell you what the problem is. First modify the PHP so it always returns some kind of response, and then it might be easier to see what's happening.

Comment: P.S. `if (responseFromServer= 1)`  because (when the request is successful) responseFromServer will be a string containing some JSON. You could display that JSON in its raw format, but if you want to get some meaning from it, you'll have to deserialise it first. On the other hand, if you literally just want your PHP to return a 1 or 0, why not return simply 1 or 0, rather than wrapping it in JSON? That seems a bit pointless. JSON would be more useful if you wanted to return several values together in an array or object.

Comment: @ADyson. Thanks for the advise. I am not a fulltime programmer. This might be a silly question, but how else do I return the variable if not is JSON. Will the C# application still recognize and use the variable if I display a `$phpVariable`?

Comment: " how else do I return the variable if not is JSON" ...in any format you like. JSON, XML, base64, morse code...anything really. When you return the value, whatever it was in PHP, it gets turned into plain text - that's the only way a HTTP response can carry data (aside from binary file data). So on the C# side you will always end up with a simple string to begin with. Then you have to know what the string represents - so if you know the string is going to be formatted as JSON, you use the right code to deserialise that, or if it's XML, you deserialise it using XML-reading code, etc.

Comment: So my point was, if all you're going to return is a single number, then just return that single number, literally. e.g. `if($SToken= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
echo $SToken->cnt);  
} else { echo 0; }` - and that's all you'd need. The HTTP response body would then simply consist of that number and nothing else. Then when you receive it in C# as a string, you know it's just a simple number. You can cast it as an integer if you need to, but otherwise you can just display it in a messagebox immediately.

Comment: @ADyson. Thanks for the advise. I think that I am passing the variables unsuccessfully from C# Windows Form  Application to the PHP Web-Service. Please see my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663736/how-to-pass-variables-from-c-sharp-windows-form-application-to-php-web-service). Maybe you have some advise?